# How to define a default entity listener programmatically?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

To define a default entity listener we configure this in the *orm.xml* file, like this for example:

```
<entity-mappings xmlns=...>
    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <entity-listeners>
                <entity-listener class="com.MyClassName" />
            </entity-listeners>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

Question: is there a way to define a default entity listener programmatically instead of declaring it in the *orm.xml* file?

Thank you.

Marcos

Comment: Did you figured it out finally?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, no for JPA. One possibility that I can think of is to create a base class which annotated with `@EntityListeners` annotation and make the other entities extends from it. I'm not sure if this is feasible or acceptable in your case though.

Comment: Not in my case. The listening has to be in a separated class other than my entities.

Comment: Would you mind to explain more on your scenario? As in why the listening have to be in separated class? Is it because you are not in control of the entity class i.e. other third party, or any other reason e.g. need a dependency on specific service etc.?

Comment: all my applications use a base framework that I created. So, every application have to declare the default entity listener in the _orm.xml_ file, leading to duplication. If I could create the default entity listener programmatically, I would do this only in the base framework, relieving the applications that depende on it from this job.